# Aggregate Self-Referencing Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursion

I've seen several questions/answers on how to recursively query a self-referencing table, but I am struggling to apply the answers I've found to aggregate up to each parent, grandparent, etc. regardless of where the item sits in the hierarchy.

```
MyTable
-----------
Id
Amount
ParentId
```

Data:

```
Id    Amount      Parent Id
 1      100          NULL
 2      50            1
 3      50            1
 4      25            2
 5      10            4
```

If I were to run this query without filtering, and SUMming amount, the result would be:

```
Id   SumAmount
 1       235
 2        85
 3        50
 4        35
 5        10
```

In other words, I want to see each item in MyTable and it's total Amount with all children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select t.Id, t.Amount, t.Id as [Parent Id]
    from Table1 as t

    union all

    select c.Id, t.Amount, t.Id as [Parent Id]
    from cte as c
        inner join Table1 as t on t.[Parent Id] = c.[Parent Id]
)

select Id, sum(Amount) as Amount
from cte
group by Id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c578/8)</kbd>**

Answer (score 4):

Something like that?

```
    WITH temp (ID, ParentID, TotalAmount)
AS
(
    SELECT ID, ParentID, Amount
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable cc WHERE cc.ParentID = MyTable.ID)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT MyTable.ID, MyTable.ParentID, TotalAmount + MyTable.Amount
    FROM MyTable
    INNER JOIN temp ON MyTable.ID = temp.ParentID
)

SELECT ID, SUM(TotalAmount) FROM
    (SELECT ID, TotalAmount - (SELECT Amount FROM MyTable M WHERE M.ID = temp.ID) TotalAmount
     FROM temp
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ID, Amount AS TotalAmount FROM MyTable) X
GROUP BY ID
```

Edited the query based on the comments below, now it all works.

Comment: I think the `TotalAmount + MyTable.Amount` is wrong because it gets summed below `SUM(TotalAmount)` but this is a great way to do your recursion. +1 BTW, should be `MyTable.Amount` only

Comment: This is like that in case you have more than one branches from the root to leaves. As the first query goes up from the leaves to the root, you may have more than one record returned for the same parent (one for each branch).

Comment: Nope, your right.  I was thinking they were going for a different result. I revisited the question and I think they do want it the way you have it.

Comment: @RomanPekar You're very right! Thank you! Changed the query but, admittedly, your solution is more elegant and should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE linked_transactions (id, parent_id, amount) AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id, amount
  FROM transactions
  WHERE id = $transaction_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, t.amount
  FROM transactions t
  JOIN linked_transactions lt ON t.parent_id = lt.id
)
SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum
FROM linked_transactions;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?